# How do I reorder examples on Documentation?

Tags: support, documentation

I don't find any controls for doing this. They appear in the order I wrote them.

Comment: They are ordered by votes anyway, aren't they?

Comment: Ok, I see. I just thought when writing a topic I give basic usage examples first and then a bit more elaborate, but hadn't thought about votes... of course, thanks

Comment: That means that for a documentation subject, people should upvote basic examples most inorder to have some sensible ordering though... Is that what the `pin` is for?

Comment: I believe the motivation for voting shouldn't be much different from Q&A. Naturally over time it will be ordered from "helpful for most users", i.e. beginner topics, to "too niche to be visible" anyway.

Answer (score 24):

I think the ability to set the order of examples absolutely needs to be added. I don't agree with the assumption that:

> Naturally over time it will be ordered from helpful for most users", i.e. beginner topics, to "too niche to be visible" anyway.

Most of the time the most "upvoted" answers exactly the most complicated, because they often represent the most efficient solution. We are not talking about solutions to discrete questions, but trying to provide a set of basic documentation that should be organized logically.

Comment: It makes sense on some topics, but not all...

Comment: If the situation is so particular that the order of examples doesn't matter, IMO it probably should not be a documentation topic. Making the documentation so specific will make just as difficult as pouring through the Q&A for new users.

Answer (score 11):

A proposed solution:

- allow an introduction to a topic. This is part of the topic, and the most important piece when proposing a new topic. It can have some basic code illustrations, but is not really an example. It always stays at the top.
- create 3 categories: Basic, Intermediate, Advanced. In each of these categories most upvoted examples float to the top.

How the three categories are represented is up for discussion. They could be tabs, with introduction only showing on the basic tab. The topic main page might show the basic tab (unless maybe the user has high rep in this tag?). They could be vertically sliding tabs.

Comment: This suggestion is certainly a step in the right direction.

Comment: I totally like that proposal. Maybe it should be a new, separate feature request. Otherwise it is likely nobody remembers it.

Answer (score 2):

In the end examples are ordered by community votes, so as soon as the first user votes on one of the examples in a topic the order is destroyed anyway.

So it should be avoided to create multiple examples that represent different steps of a process.

Comment: I don't know if that's helpful from a pedagogical standpoint. Typically, one would begin with introductory examples and progress to more advanced content incrementally.

Comment: @acjay I could not agree more. I am completely baffled by the inability to set the order of examples.