# documentation: enable reordering of examples

Tags: feature-request, documentation

It would be realy nice if reordering examples while editing a documentation page would be enabled,
this way - we could set the most important examples first.

Comment: Alternatively, it would be nice to be able to group the examples and order them within groups.

Comment: both would be usefull

Comment: To potential closers (as I almost was): I don't believe this to be a duplicate of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328469/how-do-i-reorder-examples-on-documentation?noredirect=1&lq=1 as this is a `feature-request` whereas the other is simply `discussion`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems in this case that the existing (and appropriate) SO design for questions and answers is constraining the design of SO Documentation in an inappropriate way.  I would expect SO Documentation to behave more as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Introduction) does, allowing community edits of a Document, possibly constrained by [Reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reputation).  The power of voting would be helpful in ranking the entire Document, but it's an awkward method of moving Examples around within a Document.  As @dayne writes in [How do I reorder examples on Documentation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328469/5025060),

> We are not talking about solutions to discrete questions, but trying
>   to provide a set of basic documentation that should be organized
>   logically.