# What percent of Meta feature requests are read or seriously considered?

Tags: support, meta

Related (but not identical because I'm not actually requesting a guaranteed pipeline for responses): [Can we have a guaranteed pipeline for responses from Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263662/can-we-have-a-guaranteed-pipeline-for-responses-from-stack-exchange)

*Very* related (but also not identical since I'm not just asking about the review process): [How are feature requests processed and discussed with the SE development and product design staff?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326608/how-are-feature-requests-processed-and-discussed-with-the-se-development-and-pro)

Currently, I calculated the following on currently-active feature requests (I'm under 10K and can't see deleted posts):
4,926 total questions tagged [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)
219 tagged with [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)
24 tagged with [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)
20 tagged with [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)
3 tagged with [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)
35 tagged with [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)
296 tagged with [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
Total: 597 responded to / 4,926 total requests = approximately 12.1% official response rate. Approximately 6% are implemented.

`<rather-pointed-remark>`Which ones get an official response doesn't seem to be a strict function of its score, because [some](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348560/reduce-the-number-of-votes-required-to-close-a-question-to-4) high-scoring questions don't receive official responses.`</rather-pointed-remark>`. OK, back to the actual question...

Do these statistics change much if you include deleted posts? For example, I had a minor feature request (for promoting a post to FAQ status) be complete. A moderator marked it as [status-complete] and closed and deleted it as no longer reproducible. Granted, keeping it around wouldn't have been all that useful to future readers, so I'm not objecting to the fact that it was deleted, but if that happens often it would obviously skew the ratio of feature requests that are responded to.

That being the case, what happens to the other 87.9% of feature requests that don't get an official response? Are these "slipping through the cracks" somehow and just being ignored? ([Allegedly not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326609/4032703), but there's currently not a good way to know what percent are actually read beyond whether they're tagged or not). Does a staff member actually read high-scoring posts? What determines which feature requests will receive a response and which ones won't?

Comment: There's also Meta SE to consider. Just looking at the sidebar in the [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag there I can see the numbers are better.

Comment: It's also probably worth noting that about 25% of feature request questions on here are voted <= 0. Some particularly low-voted ones might get status declined, but many of the others aren't likely to get much attention.

Comment: Meta joke: this doesn't get answered by an employee and lingers in limbo for a decade

Comment: @BilltheLizard Interesting... so you're saying that Meta.SE posts are more likely to be responded to? I wonder if that's because the fact that you can lose rep on poorly-received feature requests makes people more careful about what they post there. My statistics are admittedly somewhat incomplete because I didn't include Meta.SE feature requests or feature requests on other sites. You could argue that it would be worth doing the math for bug reports, too, but I didn't include that here.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yeah, that would be rather amusing...

Comment: I was assuming that it was because Meta SE is network wide, so developers/employees are more likely to look there, but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: @BilltheLizard:  I'm pretty sure I read somewhere that things like bugs and feature-requests were amalgamated across the network, so it wouldn't matter *where* it came from; it still made it into their system.  That's not something that *we* can see, but I believe that employees are capable of seeing that.

Comment: One of the other challenges is how many of the feature requests (whether actually duplicate or not) are related enough to have the same solution.  For example, there's a lot of feature requests about "question quality" some are true dups, others aren't.  Some may have responses, other don't - but yet it is something that is being actively worked on.  It is a lot of administrative work to try to personally respond to all of them (even if it means just linking them together or adding a status tag

Comment: @BilltheLizard Is there a way to pull the average score of feature requests on the respective sites and/or what percent of feature requests on each site has negative scores? That would be a good test of my theory that the ones on Meta.SE tend to be higher quality. I'm not experienced enough with the data service here to know that, though. (Not sure if that's something we could pull ourselves or if an employee would need to do that).

Comment: @BilltheLizard We're not particularly *more likely* to look there. But Meta SO also has a lot of site-specific features or is used as a testing ground for new features that later get pushed network-wide. E.g. there's 456 Docs feature requests that are going to get automagically handled by it not existing anymore... But I among others have Meta SO and SE pinned and read almost every single thing that rolls through either of them.

Comment: You must be new here. Nothing on Meta is ever "seriously" considered.

Comment: On the bright side, it looks like half of all requests that get a response also eventually get implemented

Comment: @TinyGiant On the other hand, there's still an 88% chance of having your proposal completely ignored.

Comment: @animuson Good to know - any chance of creating an answer based on that? It seems like this question would benefit from an "official" answer of some kind.

Comment: Ah, the [illusion of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illusion_of_control)

Comment: I understood that one of the first thing the new DAG group would be working on was backlogged requests: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351751/meet-team-dag-developer-affinity-growth/ Specifically the "What are they doing for Q&A?" section

Comment: There can be several feature requests for the same or similar feature, and they don't all get updated when the feature is implemented. I had to flag a moderator a couple of times to get the `[status-completed]` tag added.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343403/57475 , perhaps check my numbers and queries as I've removed duplicates from the counts to make it more accurate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**We don't know for sure**, but many employees read all the meta posts related to the projects they are working on. The best way to get your feature request in front of the person who can make it happen is to use appropriate tags. Lack of response does not mean that nobody in the company read your post. (But it is discouraging and we'd like to do better giving feedback.) Votes matter to the degree we are more likely to consider popular features that have been vetted by the community than features without much voting. Bounties are usually a waste of time and sweet, sweet meta reputation.

---

As the community has grown and as the company has grown, communication has gotten harder. And the problems are not going to get any easier. I personally hate that so many features and bug requests get proposed with hope and an earnest desire to help out only to be ignored. Meta is starting to feel like this wall:

[image: Market Theater Gum Wall]

I think the only way we can scale up this system is to empower every employee to feel free to respond on meta. But that's incredibly daunting for people who weren't already part of the Meta community when they were hired. To get an idea of what I mean, here's an excerpt from an answer I wrote on our internal Q&A site:

> Meta is a unique culture with its own customs, tradition and taboos. Like any foreign country, most people want to help you get acclimated as long as you show some interest in learning. So the first thing to understand is that there are many metas and each is a subculture of the site it's attached to. So Meta Stack Overflow consists of the people most interested in how Stack Overflow itself functions and Meta Stack Exchange attracts people interested in the entire network. Each site on the network has its own meta site that reflects both the network-wide [tradition of meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own) and its own individual quirks.

As every traveller knows, it's one thing to read about a foreign country and it's another thing altogether to be there. Add to that the difficulty of being thrust into the spotlight (since so many employees' first interactions on meta are announcing something) and you can get an idea of how much some employees dread interacting with y'all. I mean, it's no excuse for us ignoring good ideas, but it does help explain the situation a bit.

And, of course, we've been developing a nasty habit of working on whatever we are doing without consulting you all as often and as honestly as we should. That's shortsighted. One result I've noticed is that when we *do* open up, folks sometimes wonder about some hidden agenda. Worse, we cut ourselves off from a primary source of user feedback.

---

Over time, our approach to [status-*] tags has changed. When Meta was young, employees tended to make snap decisions about which bucket things belonged in. So if a feature was not likely to happen in the next `$period_of_time`, it'd get a quick [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). This cleared the post from lists of outstanding questions to address, but didn't necessarily imply the feature itself was seriously considered. It was pretty obvious the employee had *read* the post, but there was no way to know how far beyond reading the consideration had gone. (For all I know, each one was brought up and discussed with the entire engineering team.)

By the time I was hired, the situation was reversed. Feature requests are generally left untagged until they are seriously considered. I don't know exactly why that is, but one reason might that the company had grown and with more people comes greater [diffusion of responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_of_responsibility). If I decline a feature, it might prevent someone else from seeing it. Unless I'm certain the feature can't be implemented, I don't want to prevent someone else from considering it.

But it's more than that. While working with the Documentation team, I had full responsibility over the [documentation](/questions/tagged/documentation) tag and I *still* didn't mark things quickly. Just about every Friday I met with our PM, [Vasudha](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7458866/vasudha-swaminathan?tab=profile), to talk about meta questions tagged [documentation](/questions/tagged/documentation). Even though we had full responsibility over which features we would consider, we didn't immediately tag things in that meeting. Many weeks, we'd go over the same meta posts several weeks in a row before addressing them.

To understand *why* we didn't just make an official response to show we'd read each post, you'll need to first get an idea of how the suggestions might be classified:

1. Some requests were clearly great ideas (or obvious bugs) that we could just take care of.
2. Some requests were great ideas, but didn't mesh with our design goals.
3. Some requests were great ideas that we couldn't dedicate resources to because they were too complex or sequence-breaking to implement immediately. (For instance, we had many people suggest we implement some [other example ordering scheme](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328469/how-do-i-reorder-examples-on-documentation?noredirect=1&lq=1) besides voting.)
4. Some requests are not great, but come from a sincere place.

#1 is easy: Just let the OP know we're working on it and let the developers and designers do what they do so well. **Except sometimes I underestimate the complexity of a feature.**  So it always makes more sense for me to talk with the people who need to make the change before I commit to it. Once I know the answer, whether the feature can be built, I leave an answer and use the appropriate status tag.

For #2, I like to explain why feature isn't on the right track so that the OP can rethink it or help me understand the error of my ways. That's kinda a lot of work, but I find it immensely valuable to thinking through our systems. Slapping a status tag means I'll never come back to do that work. Leaving the tag off means I might get to it later.

#3 is frustrating. Like #1, I tend to bring these up with the team and figure out what the best response is. That takes time and to fully explain the reason we aren't doing it, I have to explain our priority list. The DAG team is making this a lot easier by [setting priorities in public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354125/help-set-qa-teamdag-product-development-priorities). But it still can be hard to explain that we can't fix something simple because it'll break a bunch of code and that the person who knows this stuff best is on vacation. (And when they *do* get back, it turns out the fix isn't as simple as the rest of us thought.)

Ultimately, it's #4 that caused me to hesitate most often. I get the feeling that some folks assume that when we see an idea that has tons of upvotes, the right thing to do is just implement it. And if we disagree that the idea is the right thing to do, we should just suck it up and do the will of meta or something. I guess the theory is we'd be using the wisdom of the crowds to build out the system. But meta voting routinely fails [every single criteria of a wise crowd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wisdom_of_Crowds#Four_elements_required_to_form_a_wise_crowd). As a moderator, I had to learn to be [careful with consensus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177565/1438) and that goes double as an employee.

The **really insidious** problem with #4 is that we sometimes [change our minds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/197889/revisions). (I know, right?) This is a good reason to not delete or give up on old feature requests. You never know when some forgotten idea will become relevant again.

Comment: Very interesting to read about the perception of Meta internally. For what it's worth, I regularly see the Jobs crew doing a fantastic job of answering Meta questions, whether support or feature requests. I can definitely see how making announcements could be daunting, but answering shouldn't be so bad and could be a much gentler introduction.

Comment: Now that you've answered, I'm really tempted to mark _this_ question `[status-completed]`.

Comment: @Pops Just to get my mandatory plug for my pet feature request in, can my [proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348560/reduce-the-number-of-votes-required-to-close-a-question-to-4) to reduce the number of close votes required to close a question be tagged as [status-planned] while you're at it? ;)

Comment: @EJoshuaS I just read your request, and its answers, and I'll devote some more thought to it. Off the top of my head, closing is really tricky because on the human side, it's perceived very differently by different people, and on the technical side, it's a really old feature that touches a lot of things. No promises on a status tag.

Comment: @CodyGray: Yes, that's true. When I have a chance, I recommend new employees start answering meta questions. But, unfortunately, as with many programmers on main, there's a perception that Meta is touchy and judgmental. I know it's a small thing, but people don't know how to take a meta downvote or comments suggesting they use a red, freehand circle.

Comment: Yeah…I sometimes think the red freehand circle meme has gotten out of control. I suspect at least part of the reason the freehand circle meme is so persistent is because it actually does slightly improve an image when a visual indicator is added. Still, the comments are often made in a confusing way and come across as unnecessarily hostile. The good news, though, is that we seem to have successfully retired many of the Meta memes from the early days, so there is hope yet.

Answer (score 15):

This is from MSO only...

Questions that have been (soft<sup>1</sup>) deleted:

```
[feature-request] is:question migrated:no duplicate:no             1875
[feature-request] is:question migrated:no duplicate:yes            731
[feature-request] is:question migrated:no closed:no                1576
[feature-request] is:question migrated:yes                         87
[feature-request] is:question migrated:no closed:no views:30       771

[status-declined] [feature-request] is:question migrated:no        75
[status-review] [feature-request] is:question migrated:no          0
[status-bydesign] [feature-request] is:question migrated:no        2
[status-norepro] [feature-request] is:question migrated:no         0
[status-deferred] [feature-request] is:question migrated:no        2
[status-completed] [feature-request] is:question migrated:no       7
```

I clicked on most questions on the first page of (most recent) results, and most of the questions seemed to get deleted shortly after posting by the OP, after a few initial downvotes. Many of the older questions were deleted by `RemoveDeadQuestions`.

<sup>1</sup>: I doubt there will be many which have been hard deleted, and I can't see them anyway.

Comment: I wonder if the deletions are the result of a lot of suggestions not being seen by the community, or being outright rejected by the community.

Comment: @Makoto - More than likely the latter plays a larger role of those two options. However, there are other reasons as well for deletion, for example some users don't properly use the feature-request tag when posing their question.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if that would make my statistics "worse" (because there are more questions that are being ignored) or "better" (because it's not including some obviously low quality proposals that were unlikely to happen anyway).

Comment: Strange to emphasize the distinction between hard and sift deletes here. I thought the only thing that had ever been hard deleted was the boat programming question.