# Can we improve the display for comment flags in the flag history page?

Tags: feature-request, comment-flags, flag-history

I just checked my flag history, and noticed that two fairly old comment flags had been handled and marked "Declined". However, rather than showing the comment that I flagged, the flag history page only displays the title of the Question where the comment appeared. In this case, the comment in question was on an answer, so to add to the peculiarity, the title of the question is hyperlinked to the *answer* under which the comment appeared.

To find the actual comment which I flagged and consider why my flag was declined, I had to expand the comments and scroll through the comments, reading each one until I came across one which I foggily remembered having flagged. For one of the two, I ultimately wasn't even able to figure out which question I'd flagged - so I'm unsure if it was a particularly inapplicable flag on my part, or whether maybe the comment was deleted for a different reason.

Since we're putting a heavier emphasis these on moderating comments these days, I'd like to request an improved presentation of flagged comments. Ideally, the flag history page would show the comment itself as an excerpt. If not, then the provided link should at least lead directly to the comment in question, not just to the overall question/answer.

Comment: well i just found out comment flags could be declined

Comment: Am I a fool for hoping that this would have gotten any kind of acknowledgement or consideration? Sigh.

Comment: I like this FR. But have you looked around how many other posts with the same tag we have laying around?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364131/how-to-renew-an-old-feature-request

Comment: @yivi yeah, that's why I'm acknowledging the probable futility. I hope that someday we can get to a place where sensible Feature Requests can be given some shred of priority, instead of just iterating on cosmetic changes to the site that don't fix any longstanding usability issues.

Comment: [What percent of Meta feature requests are read or seriously considered?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354713/what-percent-of-meta-feature-requests-are-read-or-seriously-considered?rq=1)